# youtube-dl options?

Tags: downloads, youtube, youtube-dl

I download video list and format to mp3 audio, i use this command

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 [url/vedio]
```

but if you stop cannot resume download Because the media is formatted.
problem is download start from begin

how to use youtube-dl to download video and format to audio mp3 and resume if stop? what option use for it?

thanks for help

Clarification : after formatted rename from .webm to .mp3

Comment: The problem remains
I think you did not understand my question
thanks

Comment: If the -c option does not work you will need to file a bug report. A work around would be to convert after the download.

Comment: Clarification : after formatted rename from .webm to .mp3

Answer (score 1):

Extracts from the `youtube-dl --help`

```
 Filesystem Options:
    -c, --continue                   Force resume of partially downloaded files. By default, youtube-dl will resume downloads if possible.
    --no-continue                    Do not resume partially downloaded files (restart from beginning)
```

Comment: The problem remains
I think you did not understand my question
thanks